# Need a way to exit a loop(something like a interrupt) for PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, opencv, pysimplegui

I am trying to write a code that functions like the included flow chart, but I have having issues exiting the last loop. Any help is appreciated[Project Flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxIbG.jpg).

We enter the final loop by pressing the defined button defined as 'Start Detection' on PySimpleGui. I want to be able to exit this loop by pressing a button defined as 'Stop Detection' , but without the window.read() function I cannot press the stop detection button and we are in a endless loop. If i include the window.read function the last bit of code will only run once and not in a loop as desired.

Code for the last loop is here:

while(1):

```
    event,values = window.read()
    if event in (None,'Quit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Filter Settings':
        changefitersettings()
    ## Put in an image for the item detection in here
        print('View the Parking Lot')
    elif event == 'Lot Settings':
        sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)
        getcountvalues = changeImage(x,np.array(sct_img))
        Settings()
        print('Lot Settings has been pressed')
        window.close
    elif event =='Start Detection':
        while(1):
            event,values = window.read()
            if event == 'Stop Detection':
                break
            else:
                sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)
                videoimage = changeImage(x,np.array(sct_img))
                #cv.imshow('hello1',videoimage[0])
                ServerUpdate = UpdateServer(videoimage[1],videoimage[2],videoimage[3],videoimage[4],videoimage[5],videoimage[6],videoimage[7],videoimage[8],videoimage[9],videoimage[10],videoimage[11],videoimage[12])
                k = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
                # press 'q' to exit
                if k == ord('q'):
                    break
            cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: do not mix different GUIs. also, opencv isn't a GUI toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use multithread if you have another job to do and it take long time.

Demo code

```py
import time
import datetime
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def job(window):
    global running
    while running:
        window.write_event_value('Event', datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        time.sleep(0.1)

layout = [[sg.Button('Start'), sg.Button('Stop')]]
window = sg.Window('Threading', layout)
running, old = False, None

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        running = False
        time.sleep(0.5)
        break

    elif event == 'Start' and not running:
        running = True
        window['Start'].update(disabled=True)
        threading.Thread(target=job, args=(window, ), daemon=True).start()

    elif event == 'Stop':
        running = False
        window['Start'].update(disabled=False)

    elif event == 'Event':
        now = values[event]
        if now != old:
            print(now)
            old = now

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: You can start the thread using the `Window` method so that the threading module isn't needed. `window.start_thread(lambda: job(window), '-THREAD ENDED-)`

Answer (score 0):

If we look at [the API](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#window-the-window-object) we see this:

> **read**
>
> - THE biggest deal method in the Window class! This is how you get all of your data from your Window. Pass in a timeout (in milliseconds) to wait for a maximum of timeout milliseconds. Will return timeout_key if no other GUI events happen first.
>
> ```
> read(timeout = None,
>      timeout_key = "__TIMEOUT__",
>      close = False)
> ```

Now, the default `window.read()` means having an infinite timeout, so you see the program basically hanging waiting for the keypress. However, the `timeout` is the number of milliseconds to wait before returning the `timeout_key` to your `event` variable, similar to later when you use `cv.waitKey(1)`. So use something like this:

```
event,values = window.read(1)
```

This gives the GUI a chance to read mouse clicks on the "Stop Detection" button.

Also note that there is a method `window.perform_long_operation()` that does background processing, which might be a neater way of tackling this?

Comment:  on the `window.perform_long_operation()`.  It's what Jason did in his answer, but rather than using the call he used the `thread` module.  You could use the method wit his funcation:  `window.perform_long_operation(lambda: job(window), '-THREAD ENDED-)`